# Once a variable assigned to a file when opened in python, what happens to the file when the variable is reassigned?

Tags: python, file, variables

If I assign a variable to a file (while opening the file), and then reassign the variable to something else, what would happen to the file? Would it automatically close or would it crash my IDE?

```
File = open("File.txt", 'w')
File = "File"
```

What would happen to the file?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: @Chris Figuring out what happens in this case is all but trivial. It depends on the specific python interpreter, the number of times the file object was referenced, when does garbag collection run, etc. All of which is not visible by "just running it" and seeing what happens.

Comment: Are you asking about what happens to the file in the file system, or about what happens to the object within the Python interpreter?

Comment: I was asking what would happen to the file as an object. Would it immediately be closed/discarded by python, or would it remain open, making the program slightly slower... @Chris: I couldn't tell what was happening to the file by just running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the term "variable" is a misnomer in Python.  In Python, everything is an object - when you assign a "variable", what you are really assigning is the *name* that references back to the object after the `=` sign.

In your case, `File` is a name reference to the object created by `open("File.txt", 'w')`.  You are telling the Python Interpreter that whenever you reference `File` in your code, you want to access the file object locked in write mode.  Then, when you reassign the name `File` to the literal string `"File"`, you are just telling your Python Interpreter that when you reference `File`, you are looking for `"File"` instead of the file object created.

Since you have reassigned the object reference but didn't retain a reference back to the original object, it is no longer accessible, and may eventually be collected by the garbage collector and be disposed of if the Interpreter deems it requires more resource and this object is no longer required.

In this case however, it is more likely that the file object will be locked in write mode and remain open until the script is entirely terminated, leaving you a blank file at the end.

Comment: Just a note: assuming the interpreter does rely on the garbage collector for cleanup (and, for example, CPython doesn't, relying instead on reference counting), unless some very specific conditions apply, the very last thing the python process will do before terminating is garbage-collecting everything. This means, the file won't be blank at the end. Still, OP should just close the file when done writing (or, even better, use a context manager)

Comment: @GPhilo *This means, the file won't be blank at the end.* - In my experience, at least with Vanilla Python, the file is created right away at `open(...)` and locked with write access until released.  i.e. when the script terminates.  The file won't be deleted.  So I'm not sure if there is a case where the file won't be blank at the end - if you observe such a case, I'd like to be enlightened as well.

Comment: No, you're right when you say that -for this code- the file is blank, because nothing writes to it. When writing my previous comment, I thought on the lines of "when is the content actually written to disk?" plus a possible "if you don't close the file you may lose the written data" (although you never said this may happen, my bad there for misinterpreting the answer).

Comment: In your scenario, the content still isn't written until the file is closed or the stream is flushed (i.e. File.flush()).  So anything written before a `File.close()` or `File.flush()` call will not be saved.  On top of that, at the initial `open('File.txt', 'w')` call, the `File.txt` would already be truncated to 0 bytes overwriting any existing data.  That's why I was interested in seeing a scenario where you didn't expect the file to be blank :)

Comment: *"So anything written before a File.close() or File.flush() call will not be saved."* That's the case I imagined and no, in this case data would not be lost. When the file object is deleted (by the GC running in the python process cleanup before exiting), it is **implicitly** closed, which causes the flush to disk. Unless you crash the interpreter badly, forcing the process to abort (and that's no easy feat), the data will be saved even if you don't explicitly flush or close the file

Comment: @GPhilo that's not the scenario I observed.  At least, not in vanilla Python.  Any file that is opened with `w` mode but not flushed or closed properly has been blank regardless of any data written to it.  Is there a particular Python interpreter that you see this happening differently?

Comment: The best I can think of to test this behaviour is open a file, write some bigish data to it (tested with 150MBs), immediately reassign the name to a string like in the OP's question, then have the program terminate without closing the file. This results in the data being correctly written and flushed to disk (on CPython 3.7/Ubuntu 18.04, at least), which is consistent wth CPython's delete-when-reference-count-reaches-zero behaviour. Tested both with `w` and `wb`, same result

Comment: I don't use CPython, so this is interesting to know how differently it behaves.  Thanks for entertaining with this train of thought, learned something new.